# How can I write a @DataJpaTest in a Spring Boot application that uses rsa keys loaded through configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-test

I followed the Spring Boot guides to set up JWT's using `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`, so I've got references to the rsa keys used for signing the JWT's in my `application.yml`:

```yaml
rsa:
  privateKey: classpath:certs/private.pem
  publicKey: classpath:certs/public.pem
```

This worked great until I tried to write a `@DataJpaTest` for testing the service layer of the application.

```java
@DataJpaTest
public class FooTest {
  @Test
  public void test() {
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

That test fails with the error:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey]
    at app//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter.convert(BindConverter.java:118)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter.convert(BindConverter.java:100)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter.convert(BindConverter.java:92)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindProperty(Binder.java:459)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:403)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:343)
```

I know the converters are available somewhere, because the same test runs fine with `@SpringBootTest`. I think I found them in `org.springframework.security.converter.RsaKeyConverters`. But I don't know how to register them so they're picked up during the `@DataJpaTest`.

I don't think those converters should be necessary for the test - `FooTest` has no dependencies right now.

How can I either set up the `@DataJpaTest` to work with this recommended spring-boot project setup, or how can I change the project setup so that I can easily write and run `@DataJpaTest`s?

Comment: its faster because it doesn't load all that other stuff. Read the docs: `Annotation for a JPA test that focuses ONLY on JPA components. ` https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get those speed advantages if I can't run the tests.

Comment: what are your dependencies and versions exactly? Also, are you sure about the **resource-server**  properties in your yaml file?

Answer (score 2):

`RsaKeyConverters` is somehow configured by `SecurityAutoConfiguration`. `@SpringBootTest` will consider all the auto configuration and hence it can setup `RsaKeyConverters` properly. But `@DataJpaTest` will only consider the auto configuraiotn that are related to testing the JPA stuff and hence it will ignore `SecurityAutoConfiguration`.

You can use `@ImportAutoConfiguration` to tell it to also consider `SecurityAutoConfiguration`. But after that, you will find that although it is considered , it will only be enabled if the spring-boot is started as the servlet mode but `@DataJpaTest` starts it as the 'none' mode. So you need to configure another property `spring.main.web-application-type=servlet` to force it to start as servlet mode.

So making these two configuration changes should solve your problem :

```java
@ImportAutoConfiguration(classes = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
@DataJpaTest(properties = "spring.main.web-application-type=servlet")
public class FooTest {


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to `@MockBean Converter<String, RSAPublicKey> rsaPublicKeyConver;` in your test class?

Comment: I tried going down this approach but got stuck. The exception happens before execution gets into my test class, when the ApplicationContext is being constructed. I don't think adding code within the test can fix this. I see the existing converters get registered in RsaKeyConversionServicePostProcessor: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/crypto/RsaKeyConversionServicePostProcessor.java#L77 by adding them to the ConverterRegistry. I don't know how to make that happen before my test starts.